# Find values that are between list of numbers

Tags: r, subset

I have two list of numbers like below.

```
x <- c(1, 5, 10, 17, 21, 30)
y <- c(2, 7, 19)
```

In my dataset, `x` divides 1 to 30 in different segments (from 1-5, 5-10, 10-17, 17-21, 21-30). Would it be possible to match these segments to numbers in `y`? (In this case, I'd want to get `c(1,5,17)` as an output because 2 is between 1 and 5, 7 is between 5 and 10, and 19 is in between 17 and 21.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `sapply` and a simple function

```
sapply(y, function(a) x[max(which(x<a))])
[1]  1  5 17
```

Answer (score 2):

`?findInterval` to the rescue:

```
x[findInterval(y,x)]
#[1]  1  5 17
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cut` is another option

```
cut(y, breaks = x, labels = x[-length(x)])
#[1] 1  5  17
```

---

Could be also done with `labels = FALSE`

```
x[cut(y, breaks = x, labels = FALSE)]
#[1]  1  5 17
```

Comment: Even just `x[cut(y, breaks = x)]` or `x[cut(y, x)]` will do it, since `cut` returns a factor, though I think it is slightly different to `findInterval` given the open/closed arguments.